# Hide unwanted files in eclipse project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to hide some files *.abc from eclipse project explorer using below plugin code in plugin.xml. But when I run the application, this creates new entry in the project explorer toolbar drop-down 'filter...' view but it is uncheck by default. How to check it by defaullt when application comes up?

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
  <commonFilter
    description="Hides *.abc resources"
    id="com.xyz.commonFilter.hideabc"
    name="*.abc resources"
    activeByDefault="true">
    <filterExpression>
        <and>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.abc"/>
            </adapt>
        </and>
    </filterExpression>
</commonFilter>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
<viewerContentBinding
      viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
      <includes>
        <contentExtension pattern="com.xyz.commonFilter.hideabc"/> 
      </includes>
</viewerContentBinding>
</extension>
```

Thanks, Tor

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from your question if you are coding a plugin or just want to hide files as an eclipse user.

As an eclipse user you can just hide files with the following steps:

1. Right click on the project in package explorer or navigator and open its properties
2. Expand "Resource" and switch to "Resource Filters"
3. Create a new filter using "Add Filter..." to hide *.abc files and they will disappear from the view

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined it as `activeByDefault="true"`. I suggest to start the app with a new workspace (or with the "clean" flag) to see the effect, because I guess it took you some iterations to have it implemented and your runtime workspace therefore does not set it *anymore* to active.